Unable to get the value of an element in HTML in Python and Selenium
I'm trying to get DE(GERMANY) and IN(INDIA) printed in to a list using class="lnsTableCell lnsTableCell--left" from the html below so that I can create a CSV later.
<div role="gridcell" tabindex="0" data-test-subj="dataGridRowCell" class="euiDataGridRowCell euiDataGridRowCell--stripe euiDataGridRowCell--firstColumn" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 73px; height: 34px; width: 100px;">
    <div class="euiDataGridRowCell__expandFlex">
        <div class="euiDataGridRowCell__expandContent">
            <div data-datagrid-cellcontent="true" class="euiDataGridRowCell__truncate">
                <div data-test-subj="lnsTableCellContent" class="lnsTableCell lnsTableCell--left">IN(INDIA)</div>
            </div><p class="euiScreenReaderOnly">Row: 2; Column: 1</p>
        </div>
        ...

<div role="gridcell" tabindex="0" data-test-subj="dataGridRowCell" class="euiDataGridRowCell euiDataGridRowCell--stripe euiDataGridRowCell--firstColumn" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 73px; height: 34px; width: 100px;">
    <div class="euiDataGridRowCell__expandFlex">
        <div class="euiDataGridRowCell__expandContent">
            <div data-datagrid-cellcontent="true" class="euiDataGridRowCell__truncate">
                <div data-test-subj="lnsTableCellContent" class="lnsTableCell lnsTableCell--left">DE(GERMANY)</div>
            </div><p class="euiScreenReaderOnly">Row: 3; Column: 1</p>
        </div>

This is my code:
def capture_data_1():
   url_scrape = "https://kibana-xxyyzzz.com/app/dashboards#/view/8d3382c0-49cd-11ed-b4e3-3d78365d2c94?_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:now-1w,to:now))"
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') # moves to /tmp
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        driver.get(kibana_eu_prd.login_url)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys(kibana_user_id)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys(kibana_user_pass)
        submit_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "euiButton__text")))
        submit_button.click()
        time.sleep(5)

        driver.get(url_scrape)
      #  countries = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.lnsTableCell.lnsTableCell--left"))) # Works but only print INDIA
        countries = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="i19971251-9fb6-11ef-b33e-c91f069ea574"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div')))
        print(countries.text)
        for country in countries:
            print(country.text)
capture_data_1()

The error I am getting is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_scrape.py", line 89, in capture_data_1
    countries = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="i19971251-9fb6-11ef-b33e-c91f069ea574"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div')))
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 105, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5609b1b7c10a <unknown>
#1 0x5609b1697460 <unknown>
#2 0x5609b16e3f96 <unknown>
#3 0x5609b16e4221 <unknown>
#4 0x5609b17295d4 <unknown>
#5 0x5609b170803d <unknown>
#6 0x5609b1726af6 <unknown>
#7 0x5609b1707db3 <unknown>
#8 0x5609b16d6c10 <unknown>
#9 0x5609b16d7bee <unknown>
#10 0x5609b1b4839b <unknown>
#11 0x5609b1b4c338 <unknown>
#12 0x5609b1b35ebc <unknown>
#13 0x5609b1b4ceb7 <unknown>
#14 0x5609b1b1b10f <unknown>
#15 0x5609b1b6a828 <unknown>
#16 0x5609b1b6a9f0 <unknown>
#17 0x5609b1b7af86 <unknown>
#18 0x7f40f2386609 start_thread


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_scrape.py", line 109, in <module>
    capture_data_1()
  File "data_scrape.py", line 104, in capture_data_1
    raise Exception(error)
Exception: Message:
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5609b1b7c10a <unknown>
#1 0x5609b1697460 <unknown>
#2 0x5609b16e3f96 <unknown>
#3 0x5609b16e4221 <unknown>
#4 0x5609b17295d4 <unknown>
#5 0x5609b170803d <unknown>
#6 0x5609b1726af6 <unknown>
#7 0x5609b1707db3 <unknown>
#8 0x5609b16d6c10 <unknown>
#9 0x5609b16d7bee <unknown>
#10 0x5609b1b4839b <unknown>
#11 0x5609b1b4c338 <unknown>
#12 0x5609b1b35ebc <unknown>
#13 0x5609b1b4ceb7 <unknown>
#14 0x5609b1b1b10f <unknown>
#15 0x5609b1b6a828 <unknown>
#16 0x5609b1b6a9f0 <unknown>
#17 0x5609b1b7af86 <unknown>
#18 0x7f40f2386609 start_thread

I have tried the following which only led to other types of errors:
#        countries = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "lnsTableCell.lnsTableCell--left")
#        countries = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="i19971251-9fb6-11ef-b33e-c91f069ea574"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div')
#        countries = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lnsTableCell.lnsTableCell--left")
#        print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.lnsTableCell.lnsTableCell--left"))).text)


Without knowing what kibana_eu_prd.login_url is it's impossible to replicate your issue

Put the DOM in the question. Other wise we don't know which element you are trying to access. The two line you have provided doesn't give any context. We don't know if it is in iframe or shadow dom.

@SA hello sir, may I know what is a DOM?

@SIGHUP hello sir, sorry I should have removed some sensitive information like URLS, but yeah I won't be able share that and even if I did, it is only bound to our network.

If you have only 2 countries as you named in the query, then you may use indexing or text, etc.
Eg of indexing:
# Germany    
"(//div[@data-test-subj='lnsTableCellContent'])[2]"

#India
"//div[@data-test-subj='lnsTableCellContent'])[1]"

On the contrary, if you have many countries in the list, then you may loop through them.
ls_countries = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-test-subj='lnsTableCellContent']")
    listed_countries = []
    if len(ls_countries) > 0:
        for country in ls_countries:
            txt_country = country.text
            listed_coutries.append(txt_country)
    print(listed_countries)

Hope this helps!

I would like to add one note on the Anand's smart answer.
When you are to get a list of elements, you should use "find_elements" instead of "find_element".
Hope this also helps!
